# Rmarkdown not responding after adding font features for pdf report

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a `.Rmd` file that produces a report I want in PDF with the following starting code:

```
---
title: "Report1"
author: "AK88"
date: "May 31, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Now I am trying to change the default font to `verdana` with the below:

```
---
title: "Report1"
author: "AK88"
date: "May 31, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: verdana
---
```

No other changes made. RStudio runs to the point of `output file: rep.knit.md` and just keeps thinking. Having inspected the folder, I figured that I have 2 new folders `rep_files` and `tex2pdf.6516` along with 2 `MD` files `rep.knit` and `rep.utf8`.

Any solutions?

After about ~20 minutes waiting:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "verdana" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.16     \setmainfont[]{verdana}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS rep.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output rep.pdf --template "C:\Users\AK88\Documents\R\R-3.3.3\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

Comment: I think MikTeX sometimes does some automatic package installation when you don't have the required packages, e.g. for the `xelatex` engine. Are you using MikTex? It can take a long time and sometimes get stuck.

Comment: Yep, I have MikTex.

Comment: Yeah, if it's the first time you've used `xelatex` it sometimes has to install a lot of things to get it working. I think in the past I have had to poke around manually in the MikTeX package manager to get things installed, but don't have any definitive advice about specific steps to take.

Comment: Just got a response, which is included in the OP. Does this look familiar?

Comment: It may be a separate issue. If you try again now does it produce the same error more quickly? Because in that case you probably have the packages installed but are dealing with a misspecified font.

Comment: Also it may just be that it needs to be `Verdana` not `verdana`, it's case sensitive.

Comment: Its still thinking ... I'll try `Verdana`, meanwhile, can you recommend any clean fonts for formal reports? I have been looking at different fonts here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts

Comment: ~20 min wait. The same message.

Comment: I can produce a quick test file with `Verdana` but not `verdana`. `xelatex` is noticeably slower than `pdflatex`, but I wouldn't think it would be *20 minutes* slower. Try changing the font in simple test files to see if the basics of font conversion are working.

Comment: Yeah, that solved the case. Thanks! Just curious, why does it take so long to produce this error...

Comment: I would guess that you have the option to install packages on the fly turned on. This will make MiKTeX try very hard not to fail. I set my options to require MiKTeX to ask me about installing any packages so that I can keep track of all of the packages I use (this is necessary under my configuration control requirements). Setting up my options this way hasn't avoided any problems, but it has allowed me to track and resolve them.